# Convert PHP to Python - API connection

Tags: python, php, api, python-requests

I have this php code:

```
<?
$data=
array (
'currentPage' => 1,
'itemPerPage' => 10,
);
$hash = base64_encode('username' . ';' . 'password');
$headers = array('Authoryzation: Basic ' . $hash);
$requestData = array(
'data' => $data
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'xxxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPTRETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMERQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($requestData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$results -= curl_exec($ch);
print($result);
?>
```

and I need to convert this to python. Well, not exactly this. Here is my py code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

login = "zzzz"
password = "yyyy"

url = "xxxx"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

# filters = [dict(status=1)]
# params = dict(q=json.dumps(dict(filters=filters)))

data = {
    'status': 1,
    'itemsPerPage': 1}
params = {'data': data}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(
    login, password))
print(r.status_code)
# print(r.content)
data = r.json()
```

This code in respons give me order list, but filters/params i used there didn't work at all. I tested different requests argumuents like data or json. Tried out different data structure like list, dict in dict, just one dict and still cannot convert this filters from php code to python. Any idea?

Besides php code i found this in documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I used POST method, data structure like in my code(dict in dict) and pass this data to json argument in requests.